# Tomcat 8 does not appear in Eclipse server list

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I want to work with Apache Tomcat 8.5 but it does not shown in Eclipse when I tried to add a new server. Only 7.0 and below are shown. How to fix this? Thanks.

*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 2*

[New Server Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoidW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Kepler (4.3) was released in 2013, Tomcat 8 was released in 2014 and 8.5 in 2016 - so your Eclipse release is too old to know about those releases. Use a newer release of Eclipse such as the current 2020-09 (4.17) release.

Comment: Oh ! I did not noticed this ("This package was released on 02/28/2014. A newer package is available here.") warning in the download before download. Thanks !

Comment: Congrats on 100k!